# Alternative to "old-fashioned", with a distinct and positive meaning?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms

Is there an alternative way to say "old-fashioned" but with a distinct positive meaning?

It could be used as a compliment in the following scenario:
**Woman**: *I want a man who can write sentences containing more than 3 words. It would be even better if he would use punctuation... I guess I am old-fashioned.*
**Man**: *You are not old-fashioned, you are **[...]***

The man can't say "You really are old-fashioned" to her and expect her to take it as a compliment. Most women would not take it as a compliment. I am looking for something a majority would take as a compliment. Best words I could come up with - decent/classy/traditional.

I am not a native English speaker, I can't come up with anything that conveys the meaning I want.

Comment: Obviously in your scenario both parties approve of being "old-fashioned", so there's no real reason to seek an alternative (the expression isn't inherently negative in all contexts). You might consider, say, *traditional[ist]*, but it's much the same in that people who denigrate the past will see these terms as negative - and those who don't, won't.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Are you looking for a different "*way to say 'old-fashioned' but with a good ring*"? Or are you looking for an alternative that does ***not*** mean old-fashioned ("*You are not old-fashioned; you are ___*")?

Comment: And please say what having *a good ring* means to you. Otherwise, no one will be able to help you.

Comment: *Traditional* is the first word that came to mind. Looking up some synonyms, *classic* might be a good fit. Not quite the same meaning, but *classy* or *refined* could also work in the given scenario.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Old-fashioned and traditional don't seem to have a distinct positive meaning in my eyes. They are neutral or slightly negative. That is how I see them. I am looking for a word/phrase which would mean - of old times, not up-do-date but still good. Like some old wine, antique furniture. Maybe you are right and there can be no clear answer to this question.

Comment: @Drew I rephrased my question, I hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: I'm old enough, and old-fashioned enough, to have appreciated the song by Eartha Kitt *An Old Fashioned Girl*. Now that really was something! http://www.earthakittfanclub.com/sheet_music/just_an_old_fashioned_girl_music.htm

Comment: @afaf12: What I meant was there are several terms *(outmoded, unfashionable, passé, antiquated, etc.)* that are invariably used negatively, but *old-fashioned, traditional* aren't inherently "loaded" in the same way. So unless your hypothetical male speaker wants to significantly change the *meaning* of the woman's words *("You're not old-fashioned, you just approve of **literacy**")*, he might as will just say *"There's nothing wrong with [good old-fashioned](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22good+old-fashioned%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) traditions"*.

Comment: I suggest that traditional is neutral, but old-fashioned is negative (obsolete, glad to be rid of). The most positive word I could think of is _a classic_ or _classical_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Old-school* is often used as a descriptor with positive connotations. Some might consider it a colloquialism, but the *OED* has citations going back almost 200 years for even the figurative sense of the expression.

Answer (score 3):

Given the example above, I would suggest

'You are not old-fashioned, you have standards'

I realise it doesn't quite fit with the sentence provided, but it's complimentary and you could change it to '..you have high standards' which, given the low threshold of expectation, might be slightly humorous also.

Comment: After considering this, I came up with 
'You are not old-fashioned, you are principled.'

Comment: or "You are not old-fashioned, you have old-fashioned values."

Answer (score 3):

Retro or vintage perhaps? Retro seems to have a more neutral ring, whereas vintage seems to have a generally positive ring to it, but is not as close of a synonym.

Comment: Another suggestion might be "classic" or more colloquial (and perhaps slightly  flirtatious), "classy."

Comment: Perhaps a combination of adjectives such as "timelessly elegant."

Comment: You could edit your answer instead of adding comments, which give you less freedom.

Answer (score 2):

> "You're not old-fashioned, you **merely prefer the classic/standard literacy paradigm**".